# Quotient Jordan property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

The Jordan property for finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ says that there exists a constant $c(n)$ so that for any finite subgroup $G$ of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ there is a normal abelian subgroup $A$ of $G$ of index at most $c(n)$, and we can embed $A$ in a maximal torus of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

I was wondering if there exists some sort of "quotient version". I am expecting some result of the form:
There exists a constant $c(n)$ satisfying the following: Let $G$ be a subgroup of ${\rm GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$ and $T_1$ be a subtorus of rank $N-n$ of a maximal torus $\mathbb{G}_m^N$ of ${\rm GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$. Assume that there exists an exact sequence $1\rightarrow T_1\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/T_1\rightarrow 1$, where $G/T_1$ is a finite group. Then, there exists a normal abelian subgroup $A\leqslant G/T_1$ of index at most $c(n)$ so that its pre-image on $G$ lies in the maximal torus (or some conjugate).

If $T_1$ is the trivial torus, this gives back the Jordan property. I am not an expert on representation theory. Some results in algebraic geometry I am working on point out to a statement like this, so I wanted to know if there is anything in the literature.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*suppose that there exists an exact sequence* $1\to T_1\to G$". Do you assume that $T_1\subset G$? Or is $T_1\to G$ allowed to be an arbitrary group homomorphism, unrelated to the context? that would sound weird.

Comment: It's a short exact sequence, so $T_1$ is a subgroup of $G$. In trying to write down a counterexample I see what the OP might be getting at. If a subgroup $G$ of $X=\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$ contains a big subtorus $T_1$ of $X$, then $G/T_1$ is either 'small' (dependent on the codimension of the subtorus in the maximal torus) or it contains a torus.

I've not seen anything like this. Can I not take the product of the normalizer of $T_1$ with the Weyl group of the remaining part of the torus? Actually, I don't even need that small symmetric group.

Does $G$ need to act irreducibly? Surely.

Comment: OK, a clearer statement is "let $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$ with a normal subgroup of finite index $T_1$ that is a subtorus (...)".

Comment: I think it's known that $G=T_1F$ for some finite subgroup $F$ of $G$ (with possibly nontrivial intersection). One can apply Jordan to $F$, and also the fact that finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_{N-n}$ have bounded order, to infer that there is an abelian subgroup $F'$ of $F$ centralizing $T_1$, of bounded index. So $F'T_1$ is abelian and has bounded index. Nevertheless here 'bounded' also depends on $N$, not only on $n$, and OP didn't quantify on $N$.

Comment: But if you have a bound on $N$ and $n$ then you can just apply standard Jordan. So I think this is either clear or false.

Comment: @Ycor Could you give me a reference for your first statement? And what you mean with possibly non-trivial intersection?

Comment: Also, I think the statement is false, it suffices to take $T_1$ acting on the first variables as
$(t_1x_1,\dots,t_{N-n}x_{N-n},x_{N-n+1},\dots,x_N)$, and then take $G_1$ to be an extension of $T$ adding elements of $S_{N-n}$ permuting the first $N-n$ variables. Since $S_{N-n}$ won't satisfy any Jordan property, then this violates what I wanted... but I think that under some mild conditions on $T_1$ this may be true.

Comment: Oops, I possibly learnt this fact here on MO, I don't remember a proper reference. Possibly nontrivial intersection: I mean we can't always require $F\cap T_1=\{1\}$.

Comment: @user73577 What do you mean by "mild conditions on T_1" ? Do you really want a bound depending only on $n$ and not on $N$ ?

Comment: @user73577 your counterexample is just the one I gave in the second comment. Which is why you will need a condition on $G$ probably, not $T_1$. Irreducible is too strong, as that probably needs $T_1=0$ or $T_1$ is a maximal torus. But I don't know the origin of your ideas, so I don't know what you would want.